# pyephemeris geocentric degrees

Tags: python, pyephem, 360-degrees

I'm using pdf of swiss ephemeris to read helio and geo longitude of a planet:
ex today venus is on 66'28 (6'28 gemini) helio. I've used this basic code:

```
import ephem
venus=ephem.Venus()
venus.compute('2017/08/24')
degrees=venus.hlon
print ('Venere helio', degrees)
```

result:
Venere helio 66:28:18.0 , all is fine

can someone explain how to get the geocentric degrees with a python code? based on pdf should be  27'24 cancer, therefore 117'24

thanks
Stefano

Answer (score 1):

You can get the ecliptic longitude this way:

```
print(ephem.Ecliptic(venus).lon)
```

The result looks close to the number you are after:

```
117:09:26.8
```